# Вставить изображение base64 в верстку. PHPMailer

Tags: email, phpmailer, вёрстка-email

Уважаемые коллеги! Возникла острая потребность в добавлении в тело письма изображений с использованием Base64. Для работы с почтовыми сервисами используется PHPMailer.

При отправке сообщения, gmail картинку не показывает. Вместо этого в коде он создает строку с тегами `<wbr>`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы изображение корректно отображалось в рассылке?

Comment: А тебя не смущает, что сам тег img - тоже текст?

Comment: Смущает) Но он ничем не отличается от основного кода в шаблоне письма

Comment: То есть, нет предпосылок для того, чтобы он стал строкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, решения данной проблемы нет. Из-за того, что Gmail не корректно работает с изображениями, закодированными в base64? невозможно в полной мере пользоваться этим форматом.